# Problem with Makefile: No rule to make target 'all'

Tags: makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run a code on Eclipse in C, however I keep getting the same Error in my make file. I have read similar blogposts, but i can't seem to solve my problem. I am relatively new to programming and not sure what the problem is.

Here is a copy of my makefile:

```
#CCE_Board_Definitions:BMI085;BMI088

COINES_INSTALL_PATH ?= ../../../..

EXAMPLE_FILE ?= bmi08x_read_sensor_data.c

SHUTTLE_BOARD ?= BMI085

include $(COINES_INSTALL_PATH)/examples/examples.mk
```

When i try to run my code I get the following error:

```
mingw32-make all 
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
"mingw32-make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

In Properties I have renamed the build command to "mingw32-make" (because I was told to do so in the guide for this code).

Can anyone think of what the problem might be?
Thank you in advance :)
Samboff

Comment: The problem is you don't have a target named `all` defined in your makefile.  There are not predefined targets in make: you have to create every target yourself.  There are only some conventional targets people use a lot, but you still have to define them.